# Можно ли создать InlineKeyboardMarkup в групповом чате?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Если бот общается с пользователем в лс, то при сообщении `/commands` ,  бот все норм создает такую клавиатуру, а если в групповом, то выдает ошибку `Chat Not Found`
, админка на нем стоит. Есть ли такая возможность или ток в лс так можно?

Comment: И где здесь C#?

Comment: @aepot я пишу на c#  и поэтому если ответ да на мой вопрос, то может на нем написать как это сделать

Comment: Да, можно -- я создавал в некоторых ботах, которыми пользуюсь до сих пор.

Comment: @AKа не подскажешь как?